# Google sign in not working in iOS - invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-signin

I am using google sign in iOS app but its showing me error .

i used Cocoapods to add sdk . when i have make all setting in project and launching app getting this

> The GOOGLE_APP_ID either in the plist file 'GoogleService-Info.plist'
>   or the one set in the customized options is invalid. If you are using
>   the plist file, use the iOS version of bundle identifier to download
>   the file, and do not manually edit the GOOGLE_APP_ID. You may change
>   your app's bundle identifier to '(null)'. Or you can download a new
>   configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.

and every thing i have added properly don't know why its not working .before that its was working i have updated my pod file to get latest google sign sdk .

my pod file have **pod 'Google/SignIn'** when i am installing pod (pod have ) its added

```
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0) 
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
```

i don't know why this came even i have not added any thing related to Firebase.

this is my 
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies

```
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Installing Google (3.0.3)
Installing GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.1)
Installing GoogleAuthUtilities (2.0.1)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleSignIn (4.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `googletest.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
```

Why its installing Firebase dependencies and google sign

how to solve this issue.

Comment: Does `FirebaseAnalytics` giving any harm to your project ? Perhaps it is doing but the error doesn't looks relevant to `FirebaseXXXX` related, what pod is doing let it do and resolve the error suggested in the details first. As per the error you should re-download `GoogleService-Info.plist` from server that matches your project bundle and don't change anything in the file. I think this plist file was modified as well.

Comment: i have not changed any thing in plist just download and added in project

Comment: and the bundle is the same in file as you have in project ?

Comment: yes its same as in project and plist also

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to fix this issue by:

- Open https://developers.google.com/mobile/add
- Pick a platform: iOS app
- App name: select existing app from dropdown menu
- iOS Bundle ID: select existing bundle id from dropdown menu
- Continue and configure services
- Make sure *Google SignIn* has a green checkmark on it
- Generate configuration files
- Download plist

The downloaded plist has the exact same values as my previous ones for `CLIENT_ID`, `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`, and `BUNDLE_ID`, but it adds a few keys including `GOOGLE_APP_ID`.

I replaced the plist file I had in my Xcode project with this new one and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and what helped me was ignoring GGLContext configuration and configuring SignIn manually instead like this:

```
NSString *googlePlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *googleInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:googlePlistPath];
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = googleInfo[@"CLIENT_ID"];
```

So here you're reading your `GoogleService-Info.plist`, getting Client ID from it and passing it to `GIDSignIn` instance.

I don't use anything of Firebase but seems like it's just a part of Google pod now.